# ImageMagick with Nivida GPU

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to Use Imagemagick with Nvidia 2080 GPU acceleration， How should I install imagemagick enviroment？

Comment: For GPU acceleration, ImageMagick uses [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). Ensure the drivers support the protocol, and (re)compile the source code with `--enable-opencl`. Note that only a few operators will benefit from the GPU. [see docs](https://imagemagick.org/www/script/opencl.php).

Comment: I tried use  --enable-opencl but i‘m not sure it is used with gpu.

Comment: Documentation now appears to be at https://imagemagick.org/script/opencl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it seems that OpenCL support is explicitly disabled for Nvidia GPUs...

https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/2545

Comment: Thank you！ @user15181635